# Trouble with Scala implicit arguments

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I have the following code witch will be the base for implicit objects:

```
trait Foo[-T] {
  def hello(obj: T)
}

trait Model extends Serializable {
  def bar()(implicit foo: Foo[Model]) = { foo.hello(this) }
}

class SerializableFoo[T <: Serializable] extends Foo[T] {
  def hello(obj: T) { println("hello from SerializableFoo") }
}

class FOSModelFoo[T <: Model] extends Foo[T] {
  def hello(obj: T) { println("hello from FOSModelFoo") }
}

object Foo {
  implicit object DefaultFoo extends SerializableFoo[Model]
}

class FOSModel extends Model {
   implicit object InnerFoo extends FOSModelFoo
}
```

When I call bar() on a FOSModel instance, I was expecting the FOSModelFoo to be used, but it happens it's calling SerializableFoo.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1: `implicit object InnerFoo` is available as an implicit *in the scope it's defined in* (or imported). If you an `InnerFoo` to be available everywhere, it should be defined in `object Foo` or `object FOSModel`:

```
object Foo {
  implicit object DefaultFoo extends SerializableFoo[Model]
  implicit object InnerFoo extends FOSModelFoo[FOSModel]
}
```

Problem 2: Implicits depend on static types, not on runtime types, so it doesn't matter what instance you use if the compiler only knows it's a `Model`. E.g.

```
val fosModel: Model = new FOSModel
```

Problem 3: since you are asking for `Foo[Model]` and not `Foo[FOSModel]`, `DefaultFoo` is the only one that fits.

I can't tell exactly what you want, but this seems like an incomplete "curiously recurring template pattern". It might be something like

```
trait Model[T <: Model[T]] extends Serializable {
  def bar()(implicit foo: Foo[T]) = { foo.hello(this) }
}

class FOSModel extends Model[FOSModel]

object FOSModel {
  implicit object InnerFoo extends FOSModelFoo
}
...
```

Comment: I tried it as you said, but it's still the same. What I'm trying to do is basically have a default implicit Foo (SerializableFoo) to use with Models (Model trait), and have specific instances of Foo (FOSModelFoo) for specific instances of Models (FOSModel).

Comment: Are you taking problem 2 into account? I.e. you can't get what you want if the _static_ type is Model for both cases. If yes, please edit the question with updated code.